# How Does One Include Bootstrap in Node Project

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, npm, npm-install

I have a MEAN stack project that was scaffolded using the basic npm command. At the moment, the Bootstrap is included using CDN:

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css')
```

My question is how can I add bootstrap using npm so the project works same as with CDN inclusion. In particular, when I run

```
npm install bootstrap
```

a boostrap directory is created within node_modules. However, if I try to include the bootstrap.css from that directory, it breaks the glyphicon fonts. Could anyone advise on how to do it?

P.S. I would also pose the same question regarding the AngularJS itself.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the browser package manager i.e 
***[bower](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower)***

Bower offers a generic, unopinionated solution to the problem of front-end package management, while exposing the package dependency model via an API that can be consumed by a more opinionated build stack. There are no system wide dependencies, no dependencies are shared between different apps, and the dependency tree is flat.

If you want more Knowledge about which is better and reliable you read this [link](https://www.quora.com/Why-use-Bower-when-there-is-npm) also.

[***Why Not npm***](http://frontendbabel.info/articles/bower-why-frontend-package-manager/)

The main difference between npm and Bower is the approach for installing package dependencies. npm installs dependencies for each package separately, and as a result makes a big package dependency tree `(node_modules/grunt/node_modules/glob/node_modules/...)`, where there could be several version of the same package. For client-side JavaScript this is unacceptable: you can't add two different version for jQuery or any other library to a page. With Bower each package is installed once (jQuery will always be in the `bower_components/jquery` folder, regardless of how many packages depend on it) and in the case of a dependency conflict, Bower simply won't install the package incompatible with one that's already installed.

> **Bower installation**

You just simple install the packages

Syntax

```
npm install -g bower
```

You can refer the ***[Doc](http://bower.io/docs/api/)*** for complete information.

**For Example:**

> **Directory structure**

```
project Folder
  + bower_components
     + bootstrap
       + dist
         + css
           + bootstrap.css
     + jquery
       + jquery.js
  + public
    + index.html
  + app.js
```

> **Now you can set the static path in app.js**

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'bower_components')));
```

> **Now you can use simply in your index.html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' />
</head>
<body>
{{{ yield }}}
</body>
<script src="/bootstrap/dist/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
</html>
```

> Screenshots

***Directory structure with app.js file***
[image]

***Normal Html File***
[image]

Comment: So, when I install bower, do I then need to create a bower.json file to indicate the packages I want? What's after that?

Comment: you can install bower when you external libraries like bootstrap, angluar etc .Yes you create the  bower.json which can help to update the libraries whenever you want. It is the front end solution and very easier to use . add the packages name into you bower.json or simply install with the package name.

Comment: I am still trying to clarify how to include things into my HTML file. In particular, how would bower management be different from that of npm? After all, npm also creates directories and downloads packages.

Comment: downvoted, please answer the op question. He wants to use npm and not bower. update: if you think he should use bower instead of npm , state your reasons

Comment: @eenagy i provide the right method how use the thing even i gave all the details. And this is the right method of using the front end library in node js.

Comment: @AkhileshSingh I did not nitpicked that bower is wrong/right, I just stated that the op's asked about including npm packages and not bower ones

Comment: @eenagy i updated my answer Know I think its fine and helpful for op question? What u will think?

Comment: Thanks @AkhileshSingh for the clarification, this is a great answer, upvoted

Comment: Most excellent! Now I know not only what bower does but also why it was created in the first place! Thank you.

Comment: @eenagy a very instructive read about npm and bower. Much appreciated.

Comment: Lastly, and addressed to all, will there ever be a case when both bower and npm should be used on a project? Am I correct to suspect that npm will still be used to manage node-related things and bower for front-end?

Comment: @AkhileshSingh I would buy you a coffee, beer or whatever for this answer!

Comment: @AkhileshSingh I am serious! If you have paypal or something I'd do it.

Comment: @AkhileshSingh, do you, perchance, know why I would suddenly get 404 errors on all of my bower components? I uploaded my project to the test server and got it to work. Then, after a few days away, I return to find it in this state. I am completely baffled as I have changed nothing in between.

Comment: @MadPhysicist did u changed anything in that or u upload a fresh copy of your project on to the server.

Comment: @AkhileshSingh I dont think so. I literally just came back to the test server after a couple of days of working solely locally. Either way, I can't exactly recall how I fixed the above issue, but I discovered that somehow onw of the bower components was missing. I deleted the entire "bower_components" directory and ran bower install again. That seemed to have done it.