# How to include jquery and bootstrap after instilling them with npm

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, npm

I was including frameworks and libraries by CDN, but I want to be more professional so I jumped to new tools to learn. I started wih NPM and I grasped all its basis like how to install, to update ....! but I puzzled how to include them in my project and when it comes to host should I add the node_modules folder too!

I know that including them this way 
  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />`
 aint the way unless why the hell is npm for

my questions are:
what is the nxt step after installing ? and how to including them in my project?
when it comes to host or save it in git should I add the folder node_modules too?
thanks all of you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Does One Include Bootstrap in Node Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37759681/how-does-one-include-bootstrap-in-node-project)

Answer (score 1):

to answer your questions:

1. What is npm for?
   Installing via npm gives you properly managed dependencies. When bootstrap is updated, you can update within your app easily.
2. Should I add the node_modules directory to git?
   No. Do not include your npm dependencies in git. Instead include your package.json file and whenever you deploy your code run npm install.
3. How to include the css in your project
   The example you gave is fine, however as you say it's not the best solution. I would recommend using a css pre processor such as [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/) to compile your css into a single file for your application to include. This makes including npm dependencies such as bootstrap much cleaner:

   `@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';`